# sql query to "iterate" and "concatenate" through table values

Tags: sql, sql-update, loops, foxpro

I have a table like this

```
name    group        id

john    employee     1
joe     intern       i1
smith   intern       i2
```

i'm wondering if there is a sql technique that will allow me to group the rows with the same group type to have something like following :

```
name               group        id

john               employee     1
joe, smith         intern       i1,i2
```

i'm looking for a query/solution in pure sql, no proprietary sql (e.g sql server, oracle...)
I'm no sql guru, so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: is this MySQL, TSQL or PLSQL?

Comment: solution differs on every rdbms, what specific database server you are using?

Comment: Specifically, you are trying to do an aggregate string concatenation.  The solution varies by database, but this has been discussed many times.

Comment: thanks guys, it's for reporting on an old foxpro DB

Comment: funny stuff happen here in this website :) why was my question rated -1 , and why did the answers disappear ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that in FoxPro, you have to combine SQL code with Xbase code. There's no SQL-only solution.